# change style of edit text in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I created application where I use theme Theme.holo.light. Now I want to change look of my edittexts to look like in Theme.Dark. How I can do that. I add something like this in styles.xml:

```
<style name="EditText.Style" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>

</style>
```

and use in xml with that edittext but doesn't work. How I can change style my edit text?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following article: 
http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

I found it very useful and practical for me. 
It will answer all your questions about theme style